# Type is not supported for deserialization of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm trying to dezerialize an array but I keep running into an error.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Profiles thingy = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Profiles>(fileContents);
```

This is the code that gives me the error:

`Type is not supported for deserialization of an array.`

This is how my JSON looks:

```
[
 {
  "Number": 123,
  "Name": "ABC",
  "ID": 123,
  "Address": "ABC"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to deserialize it to a collection of some sort - e.g. an array. After all, your JSON *does* represent an array, not a single item. Short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var people = serializer.Deserialize<Person[]>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(people[0].Name); // ABC
    }
}
```

Comment: when i Try your Code , i Get  Error  on `<Person[]>`. the Error text is :  `No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'Project.Models.Receipt[]'` . what should i do . @jonSkeet

Answer (score 6):

The JSON is a list. The square brackets in JSON indicate an array or list of objects. So you need to tell it to return a list of objects:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var profiles = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Profiles>>(fileContents);
```

Comment: I tried doing that but I get an error saying 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ProjectName.Progaram.Profiles>' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: @user3478897 I was assuming Profiles is a class you had defined.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail.