# Type System.String is not supported of an array

Tags: c#, json

I've been reading threads about deserializing json and tried a number of ways to achieve it but can't seem to make this work.
Here's what I've done so far:

**Class**

```
public class oVesselMovement : oVMLocation, IWPConditions, IVessel, IStatus      
{
     public int wpID { get; set; }
     public string charts { get; set; }
     public string latNS { get; set; }
     public string longEW { get; set; }
     public string course { get; set; }
     public double toNextWPNM { get; set; }
     public double toGoNM { get; set; }
     public string eda { get; set; }
     public string eta { get; set; }
}
```

**Root Class**

```
public class RootVM
{
    public List<oVesselMovement> jsnObj { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON**

```
{"jsnObj":[{"vmID":"1","charts":"2111","latNS":"10°29.10 N","longEW":"123°25.83 E","course":"420°","toNextWPNM":0,"toGoNM":"27","eda":"12-15-2016","eta":"11:01"},{"vmID":"2","charts":"2211","latNS":"11°29.10 N","longEW":"124°25.83 E","course":"420°","toNextWPNM":0,"toGoNM":"27","eda":"12-15-2016","eta":"11:01"}]}
```

**Deserialization**

```
[WebMethod]
public void saveVMDT(string jsnObj)
{
    RootVM rootObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootVM>(jsnObj);
    foreach (var obj in rootObj.jsnObj)
    {
        try
        {
            ...
    }
```

I've also tried converting the `List<oVesselMovement> jsnObj { get; set; }` to
`oVesselMovement[] jsnObj` but to no avail.

I keep getting this error:

> "{"Message":"Type \u0027System.String\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array."....

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25654220/5588347).

Comment: Use Json.net. I tried ur code it works

Answer (score 1):

`toGoNM` is a string, not a number. You need to use the proper types, fix it either on the C# side, or the JSON side. You have `wpID` in the C# class, but `vmID` in the JSON; and again, with the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what JavaScriptSerializer does internally, but newtonsoft's JToken handles this fine. The following code works:

```
 public class oVesselMovement //notice no ancestor class or interfaces
    {
        public int wpID { get; set; }
        public string charts { get; set; }
        public string latNS { get; set; }
        public string longEW { get; set; }
        public string course { get; set; }
        public double toNextWPNM { get; set; }
        public double toGoNM { get; set; }
        public string eda { get; set; }
        public string eta { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootVM
    {
        public List<oVesselMovement> jsnObj { get; set; }
    }

    public class MakeItSo
    {
        public const string json = "{\"jsnObj\":[{\"vmID\":\"1\",\"charts\":\"2111\",\"latNS\":\"10°29.10 N\",\"longEW\":\"123°25.83 E\",\"course\":\"420°\",\"toNextWPNM\":0,\"toGoNM\":\"27\",\"eda\":\"12-15-2016\",\"eta\":\"11:01\"},{\"vmID\":\"2\",\"charts\":\"2211\",\"latNS\":\"11°29.10 N\",\"longEW\":\"124°25.83 E\",\"course\":\"420°\",\"toNextWPNM\":0,\"toGoNM\":\"27\",\"eda\":\"12-15-2016\",\"eta\":\"11:01\"}]}";

        public void SaveVmd()
        {
            RootVM rootObj = JToken.Parse(json).ToObject<RootVM>();
            Console.WriteLine($"Parsed {rootObj.jsnObj.Count} vessel movement objects");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var makeitso = new MakeItSo();
            makeitso.SaveVmd();
        }
    }
```

Note however, that I don't have oVesselMovement as an ancestor of oVMLocation or an implementor of any interfaces. I believe the problem may lie in fields or properties on oVMLocation that are not in the json.